# Ansible Dynamic Host Vars

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

Is it possible to replace an `{{ item.name }}` in a loop then use that to lookup a hostvar?

Note: {{ item.name }} is dynamic and unknown in advance.

Host Vars are created such that:

```
existing_item_this: "1234"
existing_item_that: "2345"
```

Assume we're looping through a list where `item.name` is `"this"` then `"that"`.
I want ansible to first replace `{{ item.name }}` with `"this"` **then** lookup the hostVar.

```
hostvars['127.0.0.1']['existing_item_{{ item.name }}']
becomes
hostvars['127.0.0.1']['existing_item_this']
becomes
"1234"
```

```
tasks:
  - name: Do Loop
    uri:
      url: "https://example.com/{{hostvars['127.0.0.1']['existing_item_{{ item.name }}'] }}"
    loop: # Loop where item.name is "this" then "that"
```

Above task would run twice and call:

```
https://example.com/1234
and
https://example.com/2345
```

Is this possible?

This feels like it should be easier. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['existing_item_' ~ item] }}"
  loop:
    - 'this'
    - 'that'
```

gives

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=this) => {
    "msg": "1234"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=that) => {
    "msg": "2345"
}
```

> Q: *This feels like it should be easier. Is there a simpler way?*

A: It is possible to use [Lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins) with the [vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html#vars-lookup-templated-value-of-variables) plugin. The task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('vars', 'existing_item_' ~ item) }}"
  loop:
    - 'this'
    - 'that'
```

gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Is defining vars like below works for your scenario?

```
existing_item:
  this: “1234”
  that: “2345”
```

Then loop over existing_item.